# HTML button is working fine on computer ,but not on mobiles and tablets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, razor

The below code works perfectly on computer,but when I use a mobile(chrome) ,there is a problem.
Problem-:
When I click on Ignore button(Button with title="Ignore" ) ,it works fine .But when I click on lock or when I click on Answer( Button) ,they are not even clickable on mobile device.Even though the code works perfectly on computer ,there is a problem when clicked on a mobile device.
Here is the Razor Code Snippet-

```
<div class="display-cont col-md-8">
            <div class="pull-right">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Ignore","abc",FormMethod.Post))
                {

                 <input type="hidden" value="@Model.QuestionID" name ="QuestionID"/>
             <button type="submit" title="Ignore" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> 
</button>
                }
</div>
            <h2>@Model.QuestionText</h2>
            @foreach(var Tag in Model.TagTables)
            {
                <div id="parallelogram">
                @Tag.TagName
                </div>
            }            
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Answer","abc",FormMethod.Post))
            {
                 <br />

                 <br />
            <input type="text" id="QuestionTxt" name="AnswerTxt" class="input-lg form-control" placeholder="Answer Here!" />
          <input type="hidden" id="PrivacyMode" name="PrivacyMode" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" id="filename" name="filename" />

                 <br />
                <br />
                <div class="pull-left">

                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" id="unlock">  Locked</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success lock" id="lockit" ><span class="fa fa-lock"></span> Lock</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default lock" id="unlockit"><span class="fa fa-unlock"></span> Unlock</button>

                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="hidden" name="filename" id="filename" />

                         <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Answer</button>

       </div>

                        </div>
                <input type="hidden" value="@Model.QuestionID" name ="QuestionID"/>
            }

        </div>
```

And the Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#unlockit").hide();
        $("#unlock").hide();
    });
</script>


<script>
    $(".lock").click(function () {
        var mode = document.getElementById("PrivacyMode");
        var currentmode = document.getElementById("PrivacyMode").value;
        if (currentmode == 1) {
            mode.value = 3;
            $("#lockit").hide();
            $("#unlockit").show();
            $("#unlock").show();

        }
        else {
            mode.value = 1;
            $("#unlockit").hide();
            $("#unlock").hide();
            $("#lockit").show();
        }



});
    </script>
```

Comment: not sure if this is the only problem, but you are not closing your button tags - <button>caption</button>

Comment: There is no form and you are using a submit

Comment: @attila I am closing all the tags .I rechecked.!

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("Answer","abc",FormMethod.Post)) is for form .As I have already mentioned ,that everything is working fine on Computer,The problem is only with mobile phones.